Trouble getting rust lifetimes working for function mocking
I'm having some trouble working out how to get my lifetimes right for some mocking utils I'm trying to build.
However whatever I do I seem to run into errors with lifetimes.
I'm feeling like this should be possible, and that I'm just failing to see something very obvious, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
The idea of the code is that given a trait like
pub trait MyTrait {
  fn foo(&self, arg:u32) -> u32,
  fn bar(&self, arg:&SomeType) -> AnotherType,
}

I should be able to write something like
// Mock of the MyTrait trait.
// 
// Annoying 'a lifetime needed since bar_calls has a reference type.
#[derive(Default)]
pub MockMyTrait<'a> { 
  foo_calls: MockFunctionHelper<u32,u32>,
  bar_calls: MockFunctionHelper<&'a SomeType, AnotherType>,
}

impl <'a> MyTrait for MockMyTrait<'a> {
  fn foo(&self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
    self.foo_calls.handle_call(arg)
  }
  fn bar(&self, arg: &SomeType) -> AnotherType {
    self.bar_calls.handle_call(arg)
  }
}


#[test]
fn example_test() {
  let mock = MockMyTrait::default();
  mock.foo_calls.add((5,1));
  assert_eq!(mock.foo(5), 1);
}
// And something similar for bar.
  

With the plan being that the MockFunctionHelper can then do argument matching and tracking by just hunting for a match in a Vec<Box<dyn MockFunction<A,B>>.
Here's a complete example that fails with:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:73:9
   |
67 | impl<'a> KitchenSink for MockKitchenSink<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
72 |     fn convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&self, arg: &CustomStruct) -> u32 {
   |                                              - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
73 |         self.convert_custom_ref_to_u32_calls.handle_call(arg)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`

/// Represents the expected function calls the mock will recieve,
/// for a function A -> B.
struct MockHelper<A, B> {
    fns: Vec<Box<dyn MockFunction<A, B>>>,
}

impl<A, B> Default for MockHelper<A, B> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { fns: vec![] }
    }
}

impl<A, B> MockHelper<A, B> {
    /// Try calling each of the listed functions until
    /// one succeeds.
    fn handle_call(&self, arg: A) -> B
    where
        A: Copy,
    {
        for f in &self.fns {
            match f.try_call(arg) {
                Some(v) => return v,
                None => continue,
            }
        }
        panic!("No matching call")
    }

    fn add_call<T: MockFunction<A, B>>(&mut self, call: T)
    where
        T: 'static,
    {
        self.fns.push(Box::new(call))
    }
}

/// Trait to represent an expected function call
/// of the form A -> B
pub trait MockFunction<A, B> {
    fn try_call(&self, arg: A) -> Option<B>;
}

/// Simple argument/response pair
impl MockFunction<u32, u32> for (u32, u32) {
    fn try_call(&self, arg: u32) -> Option<u32> {
        if arg == self.0 {
            Some(self.1)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

struct CustomStruct {}

pub trait KitchenSink {
    fn convert_u32_to_u32(&self, arg: u32) -> u32;
    fn convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&self, arg: &CustomStruct) -> u32;
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MockKitchenSink<'a> {
    convert_u32_to_u32_calls: MockHelper<u32, u32>,
    convert_custom_ref_to_u32_calls: MockHelper<&'a CustomStruct, u32>,
}

impl<'a> KitchenSink for MockKitchenSink<'a> {
    fn convert_u32_to_u32(&self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        self.convert_u32_to_u32_calls.handle_call(arg)
    }

    fn convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&self, arg: &CustomStruct) -> u32 {
        self.convert_custom_ref_to_u32_calls.handle_call(arg)
    }
}

pub fn main() {}

#[cfg(test)]
pub mod tests {
    use crate::{CustomStruct, KitchenSink as _, MockKitchenSink};

    #[test]
    fn kitchen_sink_generic() {
        let mut mock: MockKitchenSink = MockKitchenSink::default();
        mock.convert_u32_to_u32_calls.add_call((1, 4));

        let arg = CustomStruct {};
        assert_eq!(mock.convert_u32_to_u32(1), 4);
        assert_eq!(mock.convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&arg), 5);
    }
}

A link to the example code in the rust playground is:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1261f72c98ad6bf701fd3dd967e71e0

The reason this fails, as the compiler says, is that the lifetimes don't match.
fn convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&self, arg: &CustomStruct) -> u32 {
    self.convert_custom_ref_to_u32_calls.handle_call(arg)
}

In this function, the duration of the borrow arg holds is limited to the time this function is executing.  However, by passing it to self.convert_custom_ref_to_u32_calls.handle_call it needs to live at least as long as 'a, which is a lifetime provided before this function is invoked.  Because of that, there is no possible way that the lifetime of the arg borrow can be at least as long as 'a.
Let's revisit the definition of MockHelper:
struct MockHelper<A, B> {
    fns: Vec<Box<dyn MockFunction<A, B>>>,
}

When you give generic arguments to a struct, what you're saying is that that instantiation must meet the lifetime requirements contained in those arguments.  What this means is that when you say MockHelper<&'a CustomStruct, u32>, you're effectively saying that MockHelper contains a borrow with the lifetime 'a.  Now, we know that it actually doesn't contain an A at all so this isn't actually true, but it doesn't matter -- this is what we're telling the compiler.  This is a clue that something is wrong with how these types are defined; they're not conveying the correct information about what is being borrowed and for how long.
What we need is a way to say "this MockHelper instantiation can work with references to CustomStruct of any lifetime, not some specific lifetime."  This feels like it could be adjacent to HRTBs (for<'a> &'a CustomStruct), and indeed, they would be useful here, if we could actually use them (HRTBs apply to trait bounds, not concrete types).
Note that this all applies to MockFunction as well!
Why don't we have this problem when we use the Fn* trait families?  Because impl Fn(&T) is actually syntactic sugar for impl for<'a> Fn(&'a T)!  This is why in many cases you can avoid specifying the lifetimes of reference arguments in Fn* traits; they're inferred to be any possible lifetime.
How can we get that same functionality here?
Well, one option is to just lean on the Fn traits.  Technically you can make this work with your own function trait as well by using HRTB syntax, but there isn't a whole lot to be gained here over just using Fn.
struct MockHelper<F> {
    fns: Vec<F>,
}

impl<F> Default for MockHelper<F> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { fns: vec![] }
    }
}

impl<F> MockHelper<F> {
    /// Try calling each of the listed functions until
    /// one succeeds.
    fn handle_call<A, B>(&self, arg: A) -> B
    where
        A: Copy,
        F: Fn(A) -> Option<B>,
    {
        for f in &self.fns {
            match f(arg) {
                Some(v) => return v,
                None => continue,
            }
        }
        panic!("No matching call")
    }

    fn add_call(&mut self, call: F) {
        self.fns.push(call)
    }
}

fn mock_function_u32(a: u32, b: u32) -> impl Fn(u32) -> Option<u32> {
    return move |arg| (arg == a).then_some(b);
}

struct CustomStruct {}

pub trait KitchenSink {
    fn convert_u32_to_u32(&self, arg: u32) -> u32;
    fn convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&self, arg: &CustomStruct) -> u32;
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MockKitchenSink {
    convert_u32_to_u32_calls: MockHelper<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> Option<u32>>>,
    convert_custom_ref_to_u32_calls: MockHelper<Box<dyn Fn(&CustomStruct) -> Option<u32>>>,
}

impl KitchenSink for MockKitchenSink {
    fn convert_u32_to_u32(&self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        self.convert_u32_to_u32_calls.handle_call(arg)
    }

    fn convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&self, arg: &CustomStruct) -> u32 {
        self.convert_custom_ref_to_u32_calls.handle_call(arg)
    }
}

pub fn main() {}

#[cfg(test)]
pub mod tests {
    use crate::playground::mock_function_u32;

    use super::{CustomStruct, KitchenSink as _, MockKitchenSink};

    #[test]
    fn kitchen_sink_generic() {
        let mut mock: MockKitchenSink = MockKitchenSink::default();
        mock.convert_u32_to_u32_calls
            .add_call(Box::new(mock_function_u32(1, 4)));

        let arg = CustomStruct {};
        assert_eq!(mock.convert_u32_to_u32(1), 4);
        assert_eq!(mock.convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&arg), 5);
    }
}

Note that by saying MockHelper<Box<dyn Fn(&CustomStruct) -> Option<u32>>> instead of MockHelper<&'a CustomStruct, u32> we have resolved the problem: the Fn will accept a borrow of any lifetime, and we no longer need the 'a lifetime on MockKitchenSink, which correctly conveys that it holds no borrows.

This is an excellent explanation of what is going on. Thanks very much.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but here is a version that satisfies the borrow checker:
/// Represents the expected functions (A -> B) the mock will recieve
struct MockHelper<A, B> {
    fns: Vec<Box<dyn MockFunction<A, B>>>,
}

impl<A, B> Default for MockHelper<A, B> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { fns: vec![] }
    }
}

impl<A, B> MockHelper<A, B> {
    /// Try calling each function until one succeeds
    fn handle_call(&self, arg: A) -> B
    where
        A: Copy,
    {
        for f in &self.fns {
            match f.try_call(arg) {
                Some(v) => return v,
                None => continue,
            }
        }
        panic!("No matching call")
    }

    fn add_call<F: MockFunction<A, B> + 'static>(&mut self, f: F) {
        self.fns.push(Box::new(f))
    }
}

/// Trait to represent an expected function call
/// of the form A -> B
pub trait MockFunction<A, B> {
    fn try_call(&self, arg: A) -> Option<B>;
}

/// Simple argument/response pair
impl MockFunction<u32, u32> for (u32, u32) {
    fn try_call(&self, arg: u32) -> Option<u32> {
        if arg == self.0 {
            Some(self.1)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

struct CustomStruct {}

pub trait KitchenSink<'a> {
    fn convert_u32_to_u32(&self, arg: u32) -> u32;
    fn convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&self, arg: &'a CustomStruct) -> u32;
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MockKitchenSink<'a> {
    convert_u32_to_u32_calls: MockHelper<u32, u32>,
    convert_custom_ref_to_u32_calls: MockHelper<&'a CustomStruct, u32>,
}

impl<'a> KitchenSink<'a> for MockKitchenSink<'a> {
    fn convert_u32_to_u32(&self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        self.convert_u32_to_u32_calls.handle_call(arg)
    }

    fn convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&self, arg: &'a CustomStruct) -> u32 {
        self.convert_custom_ref_to_u32_calls.handle_call(arg)
    }
}

struct Sink;

impl<'a> KitchenSink<'a> for Sink {
    fn convert_u32_to_u32(&self, arg: u32) -> u32 {
        0
    }
    fn convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&self, arg: &'a CustomStruct) -> u32 {
        1
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::{CustomStruct, KitchenSink, MockKitchenSink, Sink};

    #[test]
    fn kitchen_sink_generic() {
        let mut mock: MockKitchenSink = MockKitchenSink::default();
        mock.convert_u32_to_u32_calls.add_call((1, 4));

        let arg = Box::leak(Box::new(CustomStruct {}));
        assert_eq!(mock.convert_u32_to_u32(1), 4);
        assert_eq!(mock.convert_custom_ref_to_u32(arg), 5);
    }

    #[test]
    fn lifetimes() {
        (Sink {}).convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&CustomStruct {});
    }
}


While this does compile, it makes some non-trivial changes to the class being mocked. (Rather than changes to the mock helpers). In particular the additional lifetime on the KitchenSink trait and its function means that it can only accept CustomStructs that outlive the object. Whereas the original version meant it could accept CustomStructs with any lifetime.

@MichaelAnderson, I'm not sure I understand. Can you give an example of code that does not work with my version, but should?

The primary issue is that when you're mocking a trait, you don't want to (or can't) change the trait. The secondary issue is that originally the trait could be used like kitchenSink.convert_custom_ref_to_u32(&CustomStruct{}), but now that will not compile as the reference does not outlive the kitchenSink variable.

@MichaelAnderson, I've added a test case for that, which works fine. Perhaps I have misunderstood your point?
